# Mysql trigger-Increasing a table's field by 1 every time sth is inserted in another table

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I got one table of employees and one of departments.

```
DEPT(DEPTNO INT(2),DNAME VARCHAR(45),NO_EMP INT(5),PRIMARY KEY(DEPTNO));

EMP(EMPNO INT(3),EMPNAME VARCHAR(45),DEPTNO INT(2),PRIMARY KEY(EMPNO),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPTNO) REFERENCES DEPT (DEPTNO));
```

I want DEPT's field NO_EMP to have the number of employees that work in the department.

```
CREATE TRIGGER EMPL
BEFORE INSERT ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE DEPT SET NO_EMP=1+IFNULL(0,NO_EMP) WHERE DEPT.DEPTNO=NEW.DEPTNO;
```

The trigger above increases DEPT.NO_EMP by one only once.It doesn't surpass '1'.What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [ifnull()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) arguments are backwards. it's `IFNULL(value_to_test, value_to_use_if_null)`. You're testing if `0` is null, which it isn't, so you're effectively doing

```
... SET NO_EMP = 1 + 0
```

You want

```
... SET NO_EMP = IFNULL(NO_EMP, 0) + 1
```

instead,.